# Having issue with ng-click directive of angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have two buttons, one has a click event and redirects to login page.
Another button is simply used to show pop-up.But clicking on second button also redirects me to login page

This is my code

```
<div class="body"></div>
    <div class="grad"></div>
    <div class="header">
        <div>MY<span>Demo</span></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="register" ng-controller="RegisterUser">
            <input type="text" class="margin-15" placeholder="Name" ng-model="user.name" name="user"><br>
            <input type="text" class="margin-15" placeholder="Date Of Birth" ng-model="user.dob" name="user"><br>
            <input type="text" class="margin-15" placeholder="Gender" ng-model="user.gender" name="user"><br>
            <input type="text" class="margin-15" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" name="user"><br>
            <input type="text" class="margin-15" placeholder="Contact Number" ng-model="user.phn_number" name="user"><br>
            <input type="text" class="margin-15" placeholder="username" ng-model="user.uname" name="user"><br>
            <input type="password" class="margin-15" placeholder="password" ng-model="user.password" name="password"><br>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" ng-click="registerUser()">Register</a>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>      
    </div>
```

I tried many possible ways, but it is not working for me.

Comment: You forgot to define `ng-click` for second button.

Answer (score 0):

If the second button that was supposed to open a modal is that

`<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>`

then it has no `ng-click` directive.

You should add an `ng-click` with a **function** that opens your **modal instance**

You can find an example [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `href="#modal"`. When you click the button, angular looks for "#modal" route in the route config. Since "#modal" route is not present it redirects you to default route.

Remove href and try to open modal using javascript. For example

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" ng-click="showModal()">Modal</a>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.showModal = function () {
    //show modal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per you described, first button/link is working fine and second button or link is also redirecting to login page.

first of all your second button is not doing this because of the first one, it is reacting like this because **second link** is searching for a page(treating #modal1 as a url) and if it won't find that page it will redirect to the landing page with having url like `#/` .you can either redirect to a page with proper URL or you have to send it to a method by `ng-click` and provide a MODAL code there.

here is a plunk if you wanna redirect to some page on second click. [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/cVIgDQ?p=preview)